# Wrong redirect with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to configure a redirect with .htaccess. This works partial.

When I open the page:
*www.example.com/workflow* -> Everything works fine

When I open the page:
*example.com/workflow* -> the redirect to *www.example.com/workflow.php* 
But it should redirect to *www.example.com/workflow* (because duplicate content)

Where is my mistake in the configuration? Can somebody help me?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/ [NC,R=301]


Redirect /facebook https://www.facebook.com/example/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^workflow/$ workflow.php [L]
```

Comment: The [L] flag, after the www redirect, causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.

Comment: So you're trying to achieve URL Canonicalization? Just want to make sure I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: The rules should work fine. Maybe there are other rules, or you have a different order than show in the question.

Comment: I want that the only correct URL is: www.example.com/workflow.
It should not matter which URL the user insert. example.com/workflow or www.example.com/workflow

I've further RewriteRules like workflow but they have the same problem

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. Your rule works fine for me.

Comment: Different computer, different browser. The same problem. Not a caching problem. Each rule that I have, the same problem. Can it be a server problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301]
```

That should fix it

Comment: No, this will cause an external loop of rules. You removed the L.